# Create new column in DataFrame from a conditional of a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (1,2,3), 'B': ([0,1],[3,4],[6,0])})
```

I want to create a new column called test that displays a 1 if a 0 exists within each list in column B.  The results hopefully would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (1,2,3), 'B': ([0,1],[3,4],[6,0]), 'test': (1,0,1)})
```

With a dataframe that contains strings rather than lists I have created additional columns from the string values using the following

```
df.loc[df['B'].str.contains(0),'test']=1
```

When I try this with the example df, I generate a

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I also tried to convert the list to a string but only retained the first integer in the list.  I suspect that I need something else to access the elements within the list but don't know how to do it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

`df['test'] = pd.np.where(df['B'].apply(lambda x: 0 in x), 1, 0)`